# Understanding this capistrano deploy file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

I have a `config/deploy.rb` file that looks like this:

```
# require './config/boot'
# config valid only for Capistrano 3.2
lock '3.9.0'

set :application, 'arthousecoop'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:arthousecoop/arthousecoop.git'
set :ssh_options, {forward_agent: true}

set :deploy_to, '/home/sbp/rails'

set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

# Default value for default_env is {}
# set :default_env, { path: "/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH" }


namespace :deploy do
  # before :deploy, 'rvm1:install:gems'
  # before :deploy, 'deploy:check_revision'
  # after :finishing, 'deploy:cleanup'

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      within release_path do
        execute :bundle, 'exec thin restart -C /etc/thin/sbp.yml'
      end
    end
  end

  after :publishing, :restart
  before :restart, 'rvm:hook'
  after :finished, 'airbrake:deploy'

  # after :restart, :clear_cache do
  #   on roles(:web), in: :groups, limit: 3, wait: 10 do
  #     # Here we can do anything such as:
  #     # within release_path do
  #     #   execute :rake, 'cache:clear'
  #     # end
  #   end
  # end

end
```

1. What does the `linked_files` and `linked_dirs` sections do?

The documentation says:

> :linked_files default: [] Listed files will be symlinked from the
>   shared folder of the application into each release directory during
>   deployment. Can be used for persistent configuration files like
>   database.yml. See Structure for the exact directories.

I don't really get what that means? What does symlink mean?

2. What does the `on roles` section mean? What does the `on` method do?

   ```
   task :restart do
   on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
     within release_path do
       execute :bundle, 'exec thin restart -C /etc/thin/sbp.yml'
     end
   ```

is `release_path` a Capistrano method?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link